# Keyboard Input to trigger .addClass()

Tags: jquery, keypress, addclass

Between keypress/keydown/trigger/event, i'm not sure which is the best for what i want to do.

I want a function that when i hold a key down, then click on an element, a css effect will be added to it.

For example:

I hold spacebar, then click an img element. It gains a class that moves it some distance, and gives it a border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it for alt click,

```
$("div").click(function(e) {
    if (e.altKey) {
        alert('clicked')
    }
});
```

You can also do it using the control key `ctrlKey` or shift key `shiftKey`. 
Spacebar have it's special uses and it should not be used for this purpose.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/8ZzJM/

Comment: WOrks perfect for initiating effects. Thanks! What if i wanted to remove all instances of that added class on keyup?

Comment: use `$('yourelement').removeClass('nameclass')`

Answer (score 0):

You can set some global variable on onKeyDown trigger, and remove this setting in onKeyUp. Then after you bind onClick function, you can check whether some key in pressed.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2009/06/16/ctrl-key-combination-simple-jquery-plugin/

Those plugins might help you with your issue.